# Flutter bloc 8 some error in Either / fold return with async

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, dartz

I am migrating my project to the new version of Flutter and I use the BloC package. As you know Bloc has been updated and it has changed most of its code, so now I am adapting mine, but I have some bugs.

> The argument type 'Future Function(bool)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'UserState Function(bool)

> The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type.

**Before :**

```
  Stream<UserState> _validate(ValidateEvent event) async* {

    final successOrFailure = await services.validate();
    
    yield* successOrFailure.fold(
      (sucess) async* {
        final session = await services.getSession();
        yield* session.fold(
          (session) async* {
            yield UserSuccess(session);

            yield UserLogged(session);
          },
          (failure) async* {
            yield UserError(failure.message);
          },
        );
      },
      (failure) async* {
        yield UserError(failure.message);
      },
    );
  }
```

**After :**

```
UserBloc({this.services}) : super(UserInitial()) {
    on<ValidateEvent>(_onValidate);
  }

void _onValidate(
    ValidateEvent event,
    Emitter<UserState> emit,
  ) async {

    final successOrFailure = await services.validate();
    
    emit(
      successOrFailure.fold(
        (success) async {
          final session = await services.getSession();
          emit(
            session.fold(
              (session) { // ! The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type.
                emit(UserSuccess(session));

                emit(UserLogged(session));
              },
              (failure) { // ! The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type.
                emit(UserError(failure.message));
              },
            ),
          );
        }, // ! The argument type 'Future<Null> Function(bool)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'UserState Function(bool)
        (failure) { // ! The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type.
          emit(UserError(failure.message));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

I need to have that async inside because I call the service again, and about the body, it seems to me that I have to return it somehow but I have some logic inside and I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only things you can `emit` are instances of your state type, in this case `UserState`.  Instead of trying to emit a Future, you should `await` it instead.

```dart
void _onValidate(
    ValidateEvent event,
    Emitter<UserState> emit,
  ) async {

    final successOrFailure = await services.validate();
    
    await successOrFailure.fold( // This will return FutureOr<Null>
      (success) async {
        final session = await services.getSession();
        session.fold( // This isn't asynchronous, so no need to await here
          (session) {
            emit(UserSuccess(session));

            emit(UserLogged(session));
          },
          (failure) {
            emit(UserError(failure.message));
          },
        );
      },
      (failure) {
        emit(UserError(failure.message));
      },
    );
  }
```